# How to send cookies when downloading file in chrome.downloads.download function in content scripts of chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.downloads.download({
  url: "url",
  //cookies here...

});
```

I want to pass the cookies to the download request

Comment: The API sends cookies automatically but content scripts can't use chrome.downloads API, you need a background script or a popup script, see the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)..

Comment: then how can send the cookies from background script to chrome.downloads.download function.

Comment: I guess, use `chrome.cookies` API to set the cookie.